# User activity representation for Prediction/ML

Tags: machine-learning, preprocessing

I want to predict future user activities (e.g., account cancellation) but I don't know how I'm supposed to represent the data.

The raw data is a sequence of all activities by all users:

```
2015-01-01T04:04|user1|created account
2015-01-01T05:04|user2|created account
2015-01-01T06:04|user1|changed plan
2015-01-01T07:04|user2|changed plan
2015-01-01T08:04|user1|cancelled submission
```

In the simplest prediction I'd like to label a user as 0=Cancelled and 1=Not Cancelled and subsequently would train a classifier for this label.

The question is how would I prepare the data for a machine learning algorithm (e.g. SVM or logistic regression)?. I now have multiple rows per user which are ordered by the time they happened, but I'm thinking of having only one row per user. How would I represent the activities? Furthermore, the number of activities per user is not limited (1 to `n` where `n` would hardly ever exceed `10`), and the the number of features per activity can be large (up to 100 features).

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me out here :-)

Thx

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! When you make your prediction, what inputs do you intend to use other than the user ID?